# Rails 3.2 Asset Pipeline + Custom Theme + Bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

Hoping someone can help me as I'm going crazy reading/attempting everything to get my CSS files loaded in production, but they either don't show or I get a 404 error.

My 3.2 RoR app is using a mix of a purchased theme and bootstrap.  Of course everything looks great in dev, but once I push to production nothing works correctly.

Additionally, I have 2 layouts, application.html.erb and homepage.html.erb.  Application.html.erb calls to an additional CSS as described below.

I have the following in my app/assets/stylesheets directory:

```
stylesheets
+compiled
 --theme.css #references bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css
 --custom_theme.css  #additional CSS used in application.html.erb
+vendor
 --animate.css
 --brankic.css
+bootstrap
 --bootstrap.min.css
application.css
inbox.css
```

In my application.html.erb layout I explicitly call the following CSS:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'compiled/theme.css', 'vendor/brankic.css', 'vendor/animate.css',  'compiled/custom_theme.css', 'inbox.css' %>
```

In the homepage.html.erb layout I explicitly call the following CSS:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'compiled/theme.css', 'vendor/brankic.css', 'vendor/animate.css', 'inbox.css' %>
```

I've attempted using application.css, with *= require_tree . but this then pulls in everything, and from the homepage layout I don't need the custom_theme.  If I create a homepage.css and omit custom_theme, I still need to put in *= require_tree . as there are references within theme.css to other files in the directory.

Lastly, I've attempted explicitly pre-compiling the CSS in my config/env/prod file but this doesn't pull in the referenced css files.

*EDIT*

Per Mike's suggestion, I've added the following to my config/env/prod file:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css','compiled/theme.css', 'vendor/brankic.css', 'vendor/animate.css', 'se2b_custom.css', 'inbox.css']
```

I'm still directly calling each CSS as described above, and still receiving a 404 error in production for each.

Viewing the source of a page using my homepage layout, this is what is shown:

```
<link href="/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/compiled/theme.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/brankic.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/animate.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/inbox.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Clicking on each link results in the 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that all of the CSS files you are not including in your application.css manifest are put into your config.assets.precompile list in config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += [  'compiled/theme.css', 'vendor/brankic.css', 'vendor/animate.css',  'compiled/custom_theme.css', 'inbox.css']
```

This lets your rails app know which assets to properly minify, uglify, and preprocess into the appropriate files for production. You can read more about how awesome rails/sprockets is at doing asset precompilation automation for you [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)

**EDIT** In response to your comment:

You only need to include assets (js/coffee/css/scss) in your config.assets.precompile array that are **not** included in your application manifest **and** you plan to reference in your html/elsewhere. Rails is great about doc'ing the important notes in auto generated files, and it says in the config/environments/production.rb:

```
  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  config.assets.precompile += %w( compiled/theme.css, vendor/brankic.css, path/to/other_manifest, ....)
```

The important part is the **application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added** which means that if you need to do:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "compiled/theme.css" %>
```

OR

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "a_different/javascript_file.js" %>
```

Then you must let rails know to *precompile these into their own seperate assets files* by adding them to the config.assets.precompile array. I know it can seem confusing, but the goal of serving production assets is to combine your files automatically into as few files as possible and minify/uglify/etc to help:

1. minimize the overall file sizes being served.
2. minimize the number of unneeded requests to your server for multiple asset files.
3. revisioning to facilitate cache busting.

If you need a more detailed explanation let me know! Otherwise consider this as the accepted answer.

As for fonts, here is what I do:

1. create a directory app/assets/fonts, and put all your font files in
   there.
2. create/reuse a css file in app/assets/stylesheets and reference your fonts appropriately

for example (app/assets/stylesheets/styles.css):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "CoolIcons";
  // I have put my fonts in app/assets/fonts/cool-icons directory
  src: font-url("cool-icons/cool-icon.eot");
  src: font-url("cool-icons/cool-icon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
  font-url("cool-icons/cool-icon.woff") format("woff"),
  font-url("cool-icons/cool-icon.ttf") format("truetype"),
  font-url("cool-icons/cool-icon.svg") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="cool-icon-"]:before, [class*="cool-icon-"]:before,
[class^="cool-icon-"]:after, [class*="cool-icon-"]:after {   
  font-family: CoolIcons;
}


.cool-icon-books:before {
  content: "\e000";
}

....
```

**Troubleshooting**:

here is how I go about troubleshooting missing assets. The goal here is to simulate what is going to happen in production, but run locally:

in development (local machine), I go into my config/database.yml and add:

```
# ...(or equivalent for postgres):
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: projectname_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

from your terminal, run:

```
#this will precompile your assets as if you were deploying for production
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

now navigate to your public/assets folder that was just created, and check the contents/names of each of the files. Don't be overwhelmed by the additional characters on the end of the file names, that for cache busting.

For each of the files that you plan to reference in your html, make sure you see that respective file name in your new public/assets directory. If it's not there, then your directory structure does not match between your app/assets files and what you have put in your config.assets.precompile list.

Also, what are you using to deploy, capistrano? (I probably should have asked that first:)
And when you say:

```
stylesheets
+compiled
 --theme.css #references bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css
```

how are you referencing bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: Thanks.  I assume this would include those also referenced from within another CSS?  What about fonts called from within a CSS?

Comment: Thanks again Mike.  I've made an edit above using your recommendations, but am still receiving a 404 error.

Comment: Great advice, especially for troubleshooting.  I'll work through this and let you know if I have other questions.  Much appreciated.